# Cannot add a WCF Service Referance on a .Net5 Project

Tags: wcf, .net-5

I'm trying to add a service reference to a .NET5 project, and I'm following the directives given on the Microsoft page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide), but I run into an error message which is not explanatory at all.

Here are my steps:

[image]

I click Next:

[image]

Next again:

[image]

And at last, I hit Finish and there's the error:

[image]

The steps are simple and straightforward, I can add the service through a WebForms application so how can I get past this error with a .NET5 application?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your service running successfully?
2. Do you add an external service or an internal service, and whether the url is automatically generated or manually entered. You can check out this tutorial for more details.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022
3. You can choose to use the `dotnet-svcutil` tool.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Comment: 1. yes it is accessible through browser, and a webforms application doesn't seem to be having problems with the service too. // 2.its an external service // 3. I tried it but it generates a .cs file and a .config file. .cs file doesn't work itself and I'm not sure where I can copy it's .config file configurations on a .NET5 project. Normally we'd insert it into a app.config file but we don't have those in a .NET file.

Comment: Did you follow the steps provided by the tutorial, check out [the second link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x#getting-started) I provided which provides steps to add a web service reference to a .NET Core web project and call the service.

Comment: I tried to follow but somehow `dotnet` command does not fully work on my machine. What I tried was just the `scvutil http://fooservice.svc` command. I'll make the `dotnet` command work somehow, and try your recommendation.

Comment: You can also try updating the service references after unchecking the **Reuse types in all referenced assemblies** checkbox in your screenshot step.